# Spectrum of $I + A$, where $A$ is a self-adjoint positive operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory

Is it true that the spectrum of $I + A$, where $A$ is a positive self-adjoint operator and $I$ is the identity, is given by just $\{\lambda_n+1\}$, where $\{\lambda_n\}$ is the spectrum of $A$?

Comment: Yes, $Av = \lambda v$ is equivalent to $(I + A)v = (\lambda + 1)v$.

Comment: You seem to assume that $\sigma(A)$ is countable. Why is that?

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Because I have the Laplacian in mind

Comment: @Riku : The Laplacian does not have eigenvalues on $\mathbb{R}^n$; there it has continuous spectrum.